# Elasticsearch multi_match at beginning of words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a little issue, I'm starting to work with Elasticsearch and have this issue when I test with my curl script.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/fcomputer/products/_search?pretty' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "sams evo",
"fields": ["title", "fulltext"]
        }
    }
}'
```

What I try to do its search after everything there contain or begin with sams and evo and I don't care about case-sensitivity.

Now it looks like it's shut be the right words when I type in and its use a kind of "or" on sams and evo.

Are there a easy way to say to the query:

1. Search in field: title and fulltext
2. If you find somthing in a field match both words (sams&evo) match after (beginning) or (100% match)
3. Return all the valid data back in a search.

I have been trying to find a match on this titles:

- Samsung 950 PRO MZ-V5P256BW - solid state drive - 256 GB - PCI Express 3.0 x4 (NVMe
- ASUS GTX950-2G grafikkort - GF GTX 950 - 2 G
- ASUS GTX950-OC-2GD5 grafikkort - GF GTX 950 - 2 GB
- Zebra Z-Ultimate 5A - permanentklæbende blank polyestertape - 950 stk.
- Kyocera TK 950 - sort - original - tonerpatron

The only match here shut be (Samsung 950 PRO) if I use the search term "Samsung 950" but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "sam evo",
      "type": "cross_fields",
      "operator": "and",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "fulltext"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

use this setting

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": { 
                    "type":     "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter" 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and mapping

```
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "autocomplete",
      "search_analyzer": "standard"
    },
    "fulltext": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "autocomplete",
      "search_analyzer": "standard"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its still not search in the begning of of the word like "samsung 750 evo" will not be found with this query.

Comment: Try now with the setting and mapping.

Comment: Can you build a curl for it? can see what you mean but not understand how to use it, i'm very new for Elasticsearch for now :)

Comment: i Stille have a issue, when i try to add "properties" its can't i get this error: {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Mapper for [Fulltext] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [Fulltext] has different [analyzer]]"
    } ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Mapper for [Fulltext] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [Fulltext] has different [analyzer]]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}

Comment: you'll have to delete amd reindex your data, with those setting and mapping.

Comment: you cant change the mapping after they have been created.

Comment: Hmm, very confusing right now, reindex how can i do it?

Comment: create a new index with those setting and mapping, and reindex using reindex api

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Comment: Perfect thanks, that i don't know :) what i do this time, its just remove the index and then build it back, its working fine we are not live yet! :) thanks so much for the help